# Custom loss function with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am trying to write a custom Keras loss function but I am having issues with implementing and debugging my code. My target vector is:

`y_pred = [p_conf, p_class_1, p_class_2]`

where, `p_conf` = confidence an event of interest was detected

`y_true` examples:

```
[0, 0, 0] = no event of interest
[1, 1, 0] = first class event
[1, 0, 1] = second class event
```

I get relatively good results using multi-label classification (i.e. using a sigmoid activation in my final layer and binary_crossentropy loss function) but I want to experiment and improve my results using a custom loss function that calculates the:

1. binary_crossentropy loss for when y_true = [0, ..., ...]
2. categorical_crossentropy loss for when y_true = [1, ..., ...]

This is a simplified loss function used by the YOLO object detection algorithm. I tried adapting [an existing Keras / TensorFlow implementation of the YOLO loss function](https://github.com/experiencor/basic-yolo-keras/blob/master/Yolo%20Step-by-Step.ipynb) but have not been successful.

Here is my current working code. It runs but generates unstable results. i.e. loss and accuracy decreases over time. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import losses

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    # Initialisation
    mask_shape = tf.shape(y_true)[:0]
    conf_mask = tf.zeros(mask_shape)    
    class_mask = tf.zeros(mask_shape)

    # Labels
    true_conf = y_true[..., 0]
    true_class = tf.argmax(y_true[..., 1:], -1)

    # Predictions
    pred_conf = tf.sigmoid(y_pred[..., 0])
    pred_class = y_pred[..., 1:]   

    # Masks for selecting rows based on confidence = {0, 1}
    conf_mask = conf_mask + (1 - y_true[..., 0])
    class_mask = y_true[..., 0]

    nb_class = tf.reduce_sum(tf.to_float(class_mask > 0.0))

    # Calculate loss
    loss_conf = losses.binary_crossentropy(true_conf, pred_conf)
    loss_class = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=true_class, logits=pred_class)
    loss_class = tf.reduce_sum(loss_class * class_mask) / nb_class

    loss = loss_conf + loss_class

    return loss
```

Comment: Same problem here,